# How to get a background image on this Jumbotron Class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I can't figure out how to get this jumbotron div to have the specified background image. It worked before when I had it in another project but when I imported it to another one it just stopped showing up. Everything else works so I though that I just forgot a css style or something but I tried that and I can't seem to locate any errrors. I am using bootstrap but having edited any of the values from that library and it seem to have worked fine in the other project. One thing that might be causing would the version of bootstrap I got this segment of code from a Bootstrap Version 3.0.0 currently I am using Version 3.3.4. Not sure if that has anything to do with it though. As a last note the image works because I have it showing up for different divs on the page.

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="topTitle">
                <div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <h1>Insert <span>Topic</span></h1>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url('images/intro-bg.jpg') !important;

    background-attachment: fixed !important;
}

.jumbotron p {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.jumbotron .topTitle h1 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Result
[image: Incorect]

Comment: Have you examined the page using Firefox/Chrome's developer tools to see the applied and computed CSS?  That should tell you immediately what is happening.  In future please do that before posting.

Comment: Ok, I didn't even know that existed

Comment: Sooooo how would I go about doing that.

Comment: You open the target page in the browser and open Developer Tools from the Tools menu (Ctrl+Shift+I also works). Then take some time to look around, and read the online documentation. The dev tools are an _extremely_ powerful set of capabilities that let you examine exactly what is happening as your HTML, CSS and Javascript interact to render a page.  Learning how to use it will be an extremely good investment of a couple of hours.

Comment: Ohhhhh you mean't the inspect tool I didn't know the official name of it but now I know for sure the answer will be in here so thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I used the developer tools like how Jim Garrison said to and it revealed that there was nothing overriding it so it should work. So I randomly tryed to put the style in directly into the html like so

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background: url('images/intro-bg.jpg'); background-attachment: fixed;">
```

For whatever reason this appeared to work so I hope whoever in the future has this problem can be helped by this..... or come up with a better solution.